# No such file or directory when Installing Play 2.2.2 in OS X

Tags: java, macos, playframework, java-home

When trying to install play 2.2.2 and running it, an error apperas:

```
/Users/NoePodesta/play-2.2.0/play: line 70: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong here??

I have already set this in the .bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/xxxx/play-2.2.0  
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to close and open terminal again and then use `java -version` and `javac -version` commands to verify that paths to Java are OK

Comment: I already do that, and it ok.

Comment: what does comman `echo $JAVA_HOME` say ?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME says       /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk

Comment: It's wrong, it should point the folder... anyway try to remove this line from your bash file, Play script will try use `java` command instead, so it should point correctly to installed version with no problem (OSX Mavericks here)

Comment: If delete this line, instead it says: `/Users/NoePodesta/play-2.2.0/play: line 70: /Library/Java/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory`